# SwiftUI navigation does not work in iOS15

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uihostingcontroller

I am want to navigate from UIKIT view controller to SwiftUI screen.

On button Tap in UIVIewcontroller

```
-(IBAction)buttonTap {
    let SwiftUIController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIScreen())
    navigationController?.pushViewController(SwiftUIController, animated: true)
}
```

SwiftUI screen look something like this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        SwiftViewController()
    }
}
```

I am trying to push another SwiftUI screen from UIView controller same code is working in iOS 16 but not working in iOS15.5
Please check

Comment: You have both a `NavigationView` in SwiftUI _and_ a `UINavigationController` in UIKit?

Comment: Yes to navigation from UIKIT i am using UINavigationController

Comment: But you _also_ have a `NavigationView`. Normally you use _either_ UIKit or SwiftUI navigation. Not _both_

Comment: @jnpdx what if the project i am working on have SwiftUI class and also UIKIT class both ?

Comment: You should only have _one_ navigation system. Either SwiftUI or UIKit. If the former, use `NavigationView` and `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. If in UIKit, use `UINavigationController` and push `UIHostingController`s to it